# How do I properly use the python turtle() function in the Pythonista IDE?

Tags: python, ios, debugging, python-turtle

I recently switched to a iPad for convenience, and one of my scrips that works fine in PyCharm breaks down within Pythonista. I get an error message saying ‘Turtle’ object has no attribute ‘shape’. (Sorry for bad formatting). Here is part of the code below:

```
 ### Import required library 

import turtle

import scene

sc = turtle.Screen()

sc.title("Snake Game")

sc.bgcolor("#FFFFFF")

sc.setup(width=1000, height=600)

def up():
    print("up")

def down():
    print("down")

def left():
    print("left")

def right():
    print("right")

snake_head = turtle.Turtle()

snake_head.speed(0)

snake_head.shape("square")

snake_head.color("black")

snake_head.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)

snake_head.penup()

snake_head.goto(200, 200)

#Keyboard Bindings

sc.listen()

sc.onkeypressup(up_move, "W")

sc.onkeypressdown(down_move, "S")

sc.onkeypressleft(left_move, "A")

sc.onkeypressright(right_move, "D")

turtle.done()
```

Comment: https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/5014/shape-method-for-turtle-py

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the `turtle.shape()` method simply doesn't work yet in Pythonista. If you look in the Pythonista documentation it does appear as a valid method under the Turtle module though so I think that we can assume that it is in the works.

Another issue that I see is that even if you take out the references to `turtle.shape()`, you will also run into the issue of not having a keyboard to use your key mappings with which will cause you more grief since you will have to come up with an alternate input method.

Pythonista is a great application for iOS/iPadOS but there are quite a few things that simply do not work the same way when migrating from using python on a desktop operating system, and while it is possible to get stuff like this working, Pythonista is much better suited to automating tasks on your device than it is for doing stuff with graphics like what you are trying to do here. I would say that your best bet is to save this sort of python programming for your desktop/laptop and use Pythonista more for small automation scripts.